# Auto-submit form through Grease-Monkey

Tags: javascript, forms, greasemonkey

I have been using different script for auto submitting form like:

`document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0].submit();`

But all these refresh for endless time without submitting the form. I tried using `alert` statement which worked fine but still the form was not submitted.

```
<form id="level" method="post"> 

<br/> 
<label for="answer">Answer:</label> 


<input type="text" name="answer" id="answer" /> 

<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" /> 


</form>
```

Comment: I'm afraid your question could not be answered without seeing the page the script is running on.  Your code as it is should submit the first form of an document, nothing else, nothing less.

Comment: @Dr.Molle Question is updated with the code.

Answer (score 1):

.
With all your questions, I could try another conclusion. 
If you're trying to make a brute-force attempt to retrieve a password, the server could have identified your ip and just stall your request because you've tried too often. Or even notice you're inhumanly fast with your request. These kind of things are a base defense against brute-force attacks.

The code should work fine.

Another guess could be that the page actually does something different when clicking that button, in stead of the normal submit. So you could try simulating a click on the button in stead of submitting the form directy.

```
$('#submit').click();
```

Comment: Yea, It was very nice of you to look over my questions. Actually this is a online game where we need to enter some value according to the clues provided. But I am trying it another way since the game's name is to decrypt :P . I am brute-forcing an input form to get a suitable value to enter to the next level. And the freedom is that, we are not limited with the number of attempts. So I can brute-force it somehow. Now I am stuck over with submitting the form. :-/

Comment: Well, now I even added a timer to overcome the base-defense thing. the form still does not submits except when it is clicked physically, you know what I mean.

Comment: that actually did not stimulate submitting of the form. I mean it was unsuccessful. :(

Answer (score 0):

that line of code is right, maybe it is DOM issue, there is another `<form>` before or something else
you can try to access by ID

or jQuery :

```
$("#level").submit();
```

Comment: The Page does not reload again but the form was still not submitted. I tried this also `$("form#level").submit(function(){alert('hello world');});` which returned alert box only when the button was physically clicked.